# Creating a binary string with K pairs

Tags: string, algorithm

I'm doing the [AB problem](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13642) on TopCoder and my code passes all the system test cases except for one. This is the problem statement:

> You are given two ints: `N` and `K`. Lun the dog is interested in strings that satisfy the following conditions:
>
> - The string has exactly `N` characters, each of which is either 'A' or 'B'.
> - The string `s` has exactly `K` pairs `(i, j)` (`0 <= i < j <= N-1`) such that `s[i] = 'A'` and `s[j] = 'B'`.
>
> If there exists a string that satisfies the conditions, find and return any such string. Otherwise, return an empty string

My algorithm was to start with a string of length `N` consisting of all `A`s. Initially the number of pairs is 0. While traversing the string if the number of pairs is less than `K` I replace the rightmost As with Bs starting from the end of the string. If the number of pairs become greater than `K` then I replace the As at the beginning of the string with Bs. The number of pairs at any given time is `countOfAs * countOfBs`.

```
string createString(int n, int k) {
  string result(n, 'A'); // "AAAA....A"
  int i = 0, j = n - 1; // indexes to modify the string
  int numPairs = 0; // number of pairs
  int countA = n; // count of As in the string
  int countB = 0; // count of Bs in the string
  do {
    if (numPairs > k) {
      result[i++] = 'B';
    }
    else if (numPairs < k) {
      result[j--] = 'B';
      countB++;
    }
    else {
      return result;
    }
    countA--;
    numPairs = countA * countB;
  } while (numPairs != 0); // numPairs will eventually go to 0 as more Bs are added
  return "";
}
```

The test case which fails for me is `N=13, K=29`. `K` being a prime number there is no `countOfAs * countOfBs` that equals `K`.

The sample answer gave `"AAAABBBBBBABA"` as an answer (because you can make pairs from the first 4 As, the first 6 Bs, the second to last A, and the last B, i.e `4*6 + 4*1 + 1*1=29`)

Comment: But there is a `countOfAs * countOfBs == K`. It's called `countOfAs == K && countOfBs == 1`. Make sure your code includes that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive method which creates a solution with the least number of B's:

Start with a string of all A's, and find the rightmost position for which placing a B will create at most K pairs; e.g.:

```
N=13, K=29  

0123456789ABC  
aaaaaaaaaaaab  <-  position 12 creates 12 pairs
```

Then recurse with N = position, K = K - position + #B = 18 and #B = 1, where #B is the number of B's added so far. In the following steps, adding a B in position X will add X pairs, but also decrease the number of pairs created by the already added B's by #B; that's why we increase the required pairs K by #B at each step.

```
N=12, K=18, #B=1  

0123456789AB  
aaaaaaaaaaab  <-  position 11 adds 11 pairs
```

Then recurse with N = 11, K = K - 11 + #B = 9, #B = 2:

```
N=11, K=9, #B=2  

0123456789A  
aaaaaaaaaba  <-  position 9 creates 9 pairs
```

We've reached the exact number of required pairs, so we can stop the recursion, and the complete solution is:

```
aaaaaaaaababb
```

As you see there are only two cases at every recursion level: either K ≥ N and a B is added to the end before recursing, or K < N and a B is put at postion K and this completes the solution.

If you add N/2 B's and the value of K is still greater than zero, then there is no valid solution; but you can check this upfront by checking whether (N / 2)<sup>2</sup> is less than K.

```js
function ABstring(N, K, B) {
    if (B == undefined) {                     // top-level recursion
        if ((N / 2) * (N / 2) < K) return ""; // return if impossible
        B = 0;
    }
    if (K >= N) return ABstring(N - 1, K - (N - 1) + B + 1, B + 1) + 'B';
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) str += (K && i == K) ? 'B' : 'A';
    return str;
}
document.write(ABstring(13, 29));
```

*I initally described the solution created by this method as the lexicographically smallest, but that is not really correct. It creates a solution with the least number of B's, and places each one in its right-most position, but a solution like this:*

```
aaaabaaaabbbb
```

*can of course be made lexicographically smaller by moving the first B to the right and compensating by moving the second B to the left:*

```
aaaabaaaabbbb  
aaaaabaababbb  
aaaaaabbaabbb
```

*This transformation could of course be easily incorporated into the algorithm.*

Answer (score 1):

You can remark that it is possible to form a string for any value of K in `[0, N-1]` by building the following string:

```
B B B ... A B ... B
          ^
          index: N-1-K
```

You can extend this principle to the following values of K by using two `A`:

```
A B B ... A B ... B
          ^
          index: (N-1)-(K-(N-2)) = 2N-3-K
```

This scheme can produce all values of K in `[N, 2N-4]`.

If you use `p` `As` you can produce all values of `K` in `[(p-1)*(N-p), p*(N-p)]` by having `(p-1)` `As` on the left and one `A` moving from the right to the left.

For instance, if `N=19` and `K=23`, you can use the string:

```
A B B ... A B B B B B B
          ^
          index: 2N-3-K = 38-3-23 = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a straightforward mathematical solution to produce the optimal answer in terms of string length needed:

```
for a given pair of positive integers, (a,b),
the highest product achievable when
sum(a,b) is fixed is when a ≈ b since
a^2 is necessarily greater than (a+1)*(a-1)
```

Now our problem can be easily summarized as:

```
a*b + a_0*b_0 + a_1*b_1 ... = K,
where a + b + a_0 + a_1 ... <= N
(meaning only the first b term is included in the second sum)
```

But any number, `K`, can be expressed as

```
K = p*p' + 1*m, where p ≈ p' and m <= max(p, p')
```

where this expression minimizes the fixed sum,

```
p + p' + 1
(remember the 1*m represents our a_0*b_0 above, 
where only the a_0 is summed and b_0, which is m, is ignored)
```

So the solution requiring the least string length is:

```
let A = round(sqrt(K))
let B = floor(K / A)
let M = remainder(K / A)

min(A,B) 'a's
followed by max(A, B) 'b's
with an additional 'a' inserted M 'b's back
for a total of A + B + 1 characters
(the rest can be filled with 'a's)
```

Example:

```
N = 13
K = 29

A = round(sqrt(29)) = 5
B = floor(29 / 5) = 5
M = remainder(29 / 5) = 4

aaaaa
aaaaabbbbb
aaaaababbbb (5 + 5 + 1 = 11 characters)
       <--M 'b's back 

Solution: aaaaababbbbaa
```