# Partitioning set such that cartesian product obeys constraint

Tags: javascript, algorithm, set, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47006763/1726343), which describes the following problem statement:

> You are given two ints: `N` and `K`. Lun the dog is interested in strings that satisfy the following conditions:
>
> - The string has exactly `N` characters, each of which is either 'A' or 'B'.
> - The string `s` has exactly `K` pairs `(i, j)` (`0 <= i < j <= N-1`) such that `s[i] = 'A'` and `s[j] = 'B'`.
>
> If there exists a string that satisfies the conditions, find and return any such string. Otherwise, return an empty string

It occurs to me that this problem is equivalent to:

> Determine whether there are any 2-partitions of `0...N-1` for which the cartesian product contains exactly `K` tuples `(i, j)` with `i < j`

Where the tuple elements represent assignments of the string index to the characters `A` and `B`.

---

This yields the very naive (but correct) implementation:

- Determine all 2-partitions of the set `0...N-1`
- For each such partitioning, produce the cartesian product of the subsets
- For each cartesian product, count the number of tuples `(i, j)` for which `i < j`
- Choose any 2-partition for which this count is `K`

Here is an implementation in JS:

```
const test = ([l, r]) =>
  cart(l, r).reduce((p, [li, ri]) => p + (li < ri ? 1 : 0), 0) === k

const indices = _.range(0, n)
const results = partitions(indices).filter(test)
```

You can test out the results in the context of the original problem [here](http://requirebin.com/?gist=8c40711938e46d95570602cca7e01ee6). Some example outputs for `n = 13`, `k = 29`:

```
"aababbbbbbbbb", "babaaabbbbbbb", "baabababbbbbb", "abbaababbbbbb", ...
```

---

The complexity for just the first step here is the number of ways to partion a set: this is the rather daunting [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) `S(n, k)` for `k = 2`:

[image]

For e.g. `n=13` this works out to `4095`, which is not great.

Obviously if we only need a *single* partitioning that satisfies the requirement (which is what the original question asks for), and compute everything lazily, we will generally not go into the worst case. However in general, the approach here still seems quite wasteful, in that most of the partitions we compute never satisfy the property of having `k` tuples in the cartesian product for which `i < j`.

My question is whether there is some further abstraction or isomorphism that can be recognized to make this more efficient. E.g. is it possible to construct a subset of 2-partitions in such a way that the condition on the cartesian product is satisfied *by construction*?

Comment: @m69 I don't know if you actually read the question, I specifically linked to that. The goal is solve the combinatoric problem in the general case more efficiently, not to solve the string manipulation question. Neither of the answers given there will compute all possible partitionings; they compute a single partition in a manner that is not easy to generalize.

Comment: I saw the link "this question" and assumed it was a link to the same site that the other asked saw the question on. Sorry for jumping to conclusions.

Comment: just a very general idea: find some "arithmetically neutral" operations on these strings. E.g. for your example of 13 and 29 and strings 1 and 4: changing the second a to b can be compensated by changing positions 5 and 7 from b to a. If you could find an (partial) order on all equivalent strings and a systematic way to traverse it via such transformations, you wouls just have to find the minimal string and then work you way from there without doing all the "wasteful" steps.

Comment: @PeterLeupold That's a very good idea. I was hopeful initially that I would find that all acceptable strings were just rotations of each other, but sadly the relationship is more complicated (if indeed it exists at all) and I was not able to recognize anything.

Comment: I assume you can transform a solution with a certain number of A's and B's into every solution with the same number of A's and B's by moving some B's left and compensating by moving other B's right, as long as they don't jump over each other.

Comment: @m69 That probably suggests some kind of invariant about the sum of the indices (maybe modular sum?).

Comment: You'd have to keep track of which B's are moving left and right, similar to Even's version of Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm#Even.27s_speedup

Comment: Isn't it irrelevant which Bs are moving left and right? In any situation where moving two Bs by 1 step in opposite directions results in the Bs "crossing over", the resulting string is identical to the previous.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is a method to algorithmically construct all solutions; you're probably looking for a more mathematical approach.)*

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006763/creating-a-binary-string-with-k-pairs/47007367#47007367) to the linked question I give a method for finding the lexicographically smallest solution. This tells you what the smallest number of B's is with which you can construct a solution. If you turn the method on its head and start with a string of all B's and add A's from the left, you can find the highest number of B's with which you can construct a solution.

To construct all solutions for a specific number of B's in this range, you can again use a recursive method, but instead of only adding a B to the end and recursing once with N-1, you'd add B, then BA, then BAA... and recurse with all cases that will yield valid solutions. Consider again the example of N=13 and K=29, for which the minimum number of B's is 3 and the maximum is 10; you can construct all solutions for e.g. 4 B's like this:

```
N=13 (number of digits)  
K=29 (number of pairs)  
B= 4 (number of B's)
```

(13,29,4) =

```
(12,20,3) + "B"  
(11,21,3) + "BA"  
(10,22,3) + "BAA"
```

At this point you know that you've reached the end of the cases that will yield solutions, because (9/2)<sup>2</sup> < 23. So at each level you recurse with:

```
N = N - length of added string  
K = K - number of A's still to be added  
B = B - 1
```

When you reach the recursion level where B is either 1 or N - 1, you can construct the string without further recursions.

Practically, what you're doing is that you start with the B's as much to the right as possible, and then one by one move them to the left while compensating this by moving other B's to the right, until you've reached the position where the B's are as much to the left as possible. See the output of this code snippet:

```js
function ABstring(N, K, B, str) {
    if ((N - B) * B < K) return;
    str = str || "";
    if (B <= 1 || B >= N - 1) {
        for (var i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            str = (B == 1 && i == K || B == N - 1 && N - 1 - i != K || B == N ? "B" : "A") + str;
        document.write(str + "<br>");
    } else {
        var prefix = "B";
        --B;
        while (--N) {
            if (K - (N - B) >= 0 && B <= N)
                ABstring(N, K - (N - B), B, prefix + str);
            prefix += "A";
        }
    }
}
ABstring(13, 29, 4);
```

If you run this code for all values of B from 3 to 10, you get all 194 solutions for (N,K) = (13,29). Instead of calculating the minimum and maximum number of B's first, you can just run this algorithm for all values of B from 0 to N (and stop as soon as you no longer get solutions).

---

This is the pattern for (N,K,B) = (16,24,4):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let P be function that for given AB string returns number of good pairs `(i, j), s[i] = 'A', s[j] = 'B'`.

First consider strings of length `N` where number of `B's` is fixed, say `b`. Strings that contain `(N-b)` `A's`. Call this set of string `S_b`. Min P on `S_b` is 0, with all `B's` on left side (call this string `O`). Max P on `S_b` is `b*(N-b)`, with all `B's` are on right side. This is simple check for non-existence of `s` in `S_b` with required property.

Consider operation of swapping neighbouring `BA` -> `AB`. That operation changes P for `+1`. Using only that operation, starting from string `O`, is possible to construct every string with `b` `B's`. This gives us if `b*(N-b) >= K` than there is `s` in `S_b` with required property.

Rightmost `B` in `O` can move till the end of a string, `N-b` places. Since it is not possible to swap two `B's`, than `B` that is left of rightmost `B` can move as much as rightmost `B`, ... Number of moves `B's` (`m_i`) can make is `0 <= m_1 <= m_2 <= ... <= m_b <= N-b`.

With that, finding all AB strings `s` of length `N` with `b` `B's` where `P(s)=K` is equivalent as finding all partition of integer `K` in at most `b` parts where part is `<= N-b`. To finding all strings it is needed to check all `b` where `b*(N-b) >= K`.